# Specs pass when run alone, but fail when full suite is run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

**This question is deprecated, as I removed the gem and implemented the functionality on my own.**

I have some specs that pass when run individually. But when run as the whole suite (or as the whole spec file), only the first passes, while the others fail.

Here is the problematic PR: https://github.com/jmuheim/base/pull/75

I think it has to do with the added `clerk` gem.

Just run `rspec ./spec/features/pages/show_spec.rb` and this will be the result:

```
6 examples, 5 failures

Failed examples:
rspec ./spec/features/pages/show_spec.rb:81 # Showing page offers links to browse page by page (previous page / next page) like a book
rspec ./spec/features/pages/show_spec.rb:246 # Showing page versioning generates a diff view
rspec ./spec/features/pages/show_spec.rb:227 # Showing page versioning displays empty versions if available
rspec ./spec/features/pages/show_spec.rb:121 # Showing page versioning displays versions if available (if authorized)
rspec ./spec/features/pages/show_spec.rb:111 # Showing page versioning doesn't display versions if none available
```

While when running each of them individually, they pass, e.g. for `rspec ./spec/features/pages/show_spec.rb:121`:

```
1 example, 0 failures
```

There seems to be some dependency problem, or the DB might not be reset properly, or something like that.

Here's a screenshot of the problem, the user (creator/updater) doesn't seem to exist:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you show more information from the failed specs, what is the actual failure?

Comment: Added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have to have a `current_user` (or `User.current`) available so `clerk` can set `creator` / `updater` attributes.

See: [clerk source code](https://github.com/house9/clerk/blob/master/lib/clerk/callback.rb)

In your specs you should create a stub for `User.current`. Simple example:

```
before do
  test_user = User.create!(name: 'test')
  allow(User).to receive(:current).and return(test_user)
end
```

Edit: There probably is some initialisation code in your test suite that sets up `User.current`, but it does not get called.